# How get near by BT devices list with out using coreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

How to get BT devices list from iOS app. I want to discover and connect the BT device from the iOS app. For BLE devices we will use the core Bluetooth framework to do the above operation the same way which framework used for BT devices scanning.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access it without using corebluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get BT devices without coreBluetooth. But you can list of iBeacon devices by using coreLocation framework. But u need coreBluetooth again to connect with it.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ble3Framework.framework to scan devices and it provides ZeronerBlePeripheral calsses and delegates to get list of near by device.

here is link from where you can download the example and sdk for iOS and Android:

```
http://api6.iwown.com/devcenter/tutorial.html
```